# Make file with multiple potential dependencies

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to make a make file for a static page generator, and I'm using `jinja` and `pandoc` so far, and the idea is to have a file structure as such

```
.
|-content
|-public
|-templates
|-Makefile
```

```
VPATH=public
TARGETS=$(find content -regex ".*(htm|md)" | sed -e "s/md$/htm/g;s/^content/public/g")

all: $(TARGETS)
   @echo fullbuild

public/%: content/%

content/%.md:
    # Pandoc script 
    pandoc -i $@ -o ${${@:.md=.htm}:content=public}

content/%.htm:
    # Jinja Script
```

The problem I'm having (At least I think that's it) is that according to me the syntax is

```
# For a final result
target: dependency
    commands

# A rule for dependency
dependency: 
    commands
```

My dependencies are in the `content` dir and my *targets* are in the `public` dir that may or may not exist yet, and almost all the files I generate will be `htm` files, and in that case if the target is `public/some/route/to/file.htm` the dependency will be any of this two `content/some/route/to/file.(htm|md)`.

I can easily generate by walking the content dir, and changing extensions.

How should I write the rules properly, so 
 - Make knows where to "watch" for changes every time I do a `make`, because right now it points that every file is up to date
 - How do I indicate properly the dependency of a file to it's content file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule:

```
public/%: content/%
```

does nothing because pattern rules without recipes [delete existing pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html), they don't define new pattern rules.

It's very simple, you should write two rules like this:

```
public/%.htm: content/%.md:
        # Pandoc script 
        pandoc -i $< -o $@

public/%.htm: content/%.htm
        # Jinja Script
```

Here's a hint: whenever you're writing a makefile recipe and you discover that you need to create a target which is different than exactly `$@`, unmodified, immediately stop what you're doing and back up: you've taken a wrong turn.